# Mocha bdd style test naming

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, bdd, mocha.js

I am using [Mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) as the test framework for testing my node.js project. And I would like to follow the BDD style to organize my tests/specs.

I used to write some tests using [cucumber](http://cukes.info/) which employs BDD style like the [given-when-then clause](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html). But for Mocha, it uses a different language to 'describe' the spec. You can have nested describe statements to describe the spec. And I want to know what the best practice is to naming the Mocha tests. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to replicate cucumber-style BDD in Mocha or how to use what Mocha offers? (*If* your question is the latter, then please don't ask about "best practices" as these are usually opinion-based. And if your question is the latter, the question should be more precise about what exactly is causing you problem.)

Comment: I actually think best practice questions are great. If you think best practice questions are just about opinion then you are admitting our entire industry has no objectivity whatsoever :)

Answer (score 1):

[mocha-cakes](https://github.com/quangv/mocha-cakes) lets you use given-when-then clauses with mocha.

Comment: there's a newer library with extensive docs: https://github.com/dotnetprofessional/LiveDoc/tree/master/packages/livedoc-mocha